# What is under the hood when a process receive a signal?

Tags: c++, linux

I am writing a program that needs to catch the ctrl-c event. And I learned that I can call `signal` function or `sigaction` function in `signal.h` to customize what to do when the process receives a SIGINT signal. But I am also curious what is the mechanism for such a signal listener. In other words, how can a process keep waiting for a specific signal while continuing to execute its code?

Comment: The operating system does this, the process is not involved.

Comment: Signals are delivered asynchronously by the operating system. Linux supports the concept of `signalfd` if you want to be able to wait on them in a synchronous fashion.

Comment: unrelated: And because the show is run by the OS, you've got to be careful of what you do in a signal handler. In POSIX systems there's literally [a list](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) of what you can do because it is much, much smaller than the list of what you can't. General rule of thumb is to set an atomic flag to tell the program the signal happened and get the heck out of the signal handler. Somewhere in the code running outside the handler the program checks the flag and takes appropriate action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process doesn't "wait" for the signal. Calling `sigaction()` tells the operating system to force the process to take the specified action when the process receives the specified signal. When this happens, the process is interrupted and forced to call the registered handler.